# How js interpretator works

Tags: javascript

It is true, that javascript works like this:

1. Does the interpreter pass 1 time throughout the code?
2. and the second time it executes the code?

If this is true, where can I find information that characterizes my question?

Comment: @deceze, that information is not about javascript, could you open the question?

Comment: There are *plenty* of Javascript-related duplicates now.